# How to justify text properly?

Tags: flutter

I am using `textAlign: TextAlign.justify` in a flutter `Text` widget and it only works if the text is wider than the screen. If the text is shorter than the available width it centers the text.

What I want is normal paragraph justification (ie. the same as a word processor) whereby long lines are justified and short lines are left aligned.

Here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: TestClass(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestClassState createState() => _TestClassState();
}

class _TestClassState extends State<TestClass> {
  double loginWidth = 40.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            border: Border.all(),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
                const Text(
                    'If you have a long line of text then the text text is wider than the screen and it justifies correctly, just as you would expect. So far so good.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                const Text(
                    'This is wrong',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                ),
            ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

Any suggestions as to what alignment I can use to handle both short and long text?

Comment: Have you tried MainAxisAlighment.start for your wrapper column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justify property would work when length of text is greater to width of container, if you want both text to start from starting use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`

```dart
child: Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
)
```

Comment: Durr, what an idiot I am, I was too busy thinking the TextAlign.justify was wrong to think about the Column!